# Make an interface optional?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface with optional properties

```
interface Foo {
   cityName?: string
   state?: string
}

const getLocation = ({ cityName } : Foo) => {

...

}
```

I always have to pass in an empty object though if I am not passing in 'cityName' or 'state'

```
getLocation({})
```

What can I do to not having to pass in an object?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Mark the parameter itself as optional

```
const getLocation = (location?: Foo) => {
  if (!location) return;

  ...

}
```

Or set default value:

```
const getLocation = ({ cityName }: Foo = {}) => {

  ...

}
```